# How to change property of UserControl on PostBack?

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, event-handling

Let's say I have a page with my custom `UserControl` (containing only `asp:Literal` and some string property) and a button. Now I want to change Literal's text on button click, so I change my control's string property in button clicked event. Like this:

```
//in aspx
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    testControl.Text = "triggered";
}
```

The problem is my Literal remains unchanged because `Page_Load` event fires first and creates my custom control, then `Button_Clicked` fires and changes property but as control is already created, it does nothing. This is my control's code behind:

```
public partial class TestControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public string Text { get; set; } }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblTest.Text = Text;
    }
}
```

I figured out that if I move any logic in custom control from `Page_Load` to property setter it will change like intended. Like this:

```
public string Text { get { return lblTest.Text; } set { lblTest.Text = value; } }
```

Is there any other (better) way to do this? My real problem involves much more complicated controls than described here, but problems remains the same: on any postback all properties set in event handlers are ignored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Moving all logic from `Page_Load` to `Page_PreRender` solved the problem. Now properties are set before logic executes. I'll wait for other answers to check if there is better solution and if there are any drawbacks of using `Page_PreRender`.

Answer (score 0):

This video might help: [How Do I: Persist the State of a User Control During a Postback](http://www.asp.net/general/videos/how-do-i-persist-the-state-of-a-user-control-during-a-postback)

Comment: That's not exactly about my problem I think. The problem was with using properties during postback that changes them. By the way, for persisting any data between postbacks I usually use something like: `public string Text { get { return (string)ViewState["Text"];} set { ViewState["Text"] = value; }`. It seems to work ok for basic properties, but I'm not sure if in every circumstances ;).